# SQL INSERT Query with String variable in it

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query in which I need to insert a string variable but I am getting errors from it.

Below is my SQL INSERT query:

```
Insert into User(Employee, Name, Address, Role, Action) 
Select distinct ur1.Employee, ur1.Name, ur1.Address, ur1.Role, ['%" + action + "%'] as [Action] FROM UserRoles ur1)";

string action="insert delete query in database"
```

I would like to insert *string* `action` into my `INSERT` statement, but I am getting lots of syntax errors.

Can anyone help me with the query?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Show us the errors please. And maybe you also need to use `FROM UserRoles ur1)` if you don't want engine complains because `ur1.Employee, ...` don't exist.

Comment: Do you want the sql for this, if so which DBMS (Sql Server, ACcess Oracle etc), or do you want cosde, if so what language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into User(Employee, Name, Address, Role, Action) 
Select distinct ur1.Employee, ur1.Name, ur1.Address, ur1.Role,'insert delete query in database' 
FROM UserRoles ur1;
```

Comment: `ur1.Employee,... doesn't exist` check out the comment of @Marco

Comment: As I've already told in my post comment, `ur1` is not defined ;)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL operator for string concatenation is `||`.

Comment: hi CodeBrikie, what do you mean by string concatenation? What do I have to replace with `|`?

Comment: @RUiHAO "adding strings". You should replace "+" by "||".

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
INSERT INTO User (Employee, Name, Address, Role, Action) 
SELECT DISTINCT ur1.Employee, ur1.Name, 
                ur1.Address, ur1.Role, 
                ['%insert delete query in database%'] 
FROM UserRoles ur1
```

Answer (score 1):

The part where you are concatenating your `action` variable to the rest of the script looks something like this after the concatenation:

```
…
  ['the string value goes here'] as [Action]
…
```

I'm now going to take a wild guess but it does seem as if you are on SQL Server or on Sybase, because of the square brackets. Now, in either of those two products, the sequences of characters enclosed in square brackets would be considered *delimited identifiers*. Using the brackets in your example does make sense for `[Action]` but seems absolutely pointless for the `['...']` part of your script. It is more likely that you meant simply `'...'`, i.e. without the square brackets, which simply stands for a string constant.

One other thing to note: there's an unmatched closing parenthesis at the end of your SQL statement.